# reading led requirements

Tags: led

I'm still pretty new to electronics and I bought an led from radio shack that said 12vdc add max. It also said 20mA and 1.5mcd which says is it's intensity. Is 12vdc the max volts and 20mA the minimum volts (one I convert it to voltage). It also confess with a built in resister

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Can you give a Radio Shack part number, so we don't have to make too many guesses...

Comment: @Peter Bennett it's 276-0209

Comment: 20 mA is current (not voltage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this is an indicator LED assembly, not a bare LED. (although I don't know what "add max" refers to.)

It includes a current limiting circuit in series with the LED, and is intended to operate directly from 12 volts, with no additional current limiting required.

If you connect it to 12 Volts, it will draw 20 mA.